# VS WinForm designer always changes custom constructor?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

All,

I'm using MSVS 2010 doing a project with C#/WinForms.
I made an object derived from the group box and I changed it's constructor so that it will take an integer variable on construction.
I added my object to the toolbox and I can successfully insert that object on the GUI designer.

But every time I make a change in the form my custom constructor is changed.

So I need a way to either fix VS so that every time I changed a form the code won't rebuild itself or I need some other way of fixing the code in my custom made object.

Basically what I am doing is depending on the parameter I passed I am creating different set of the widgets and show them to the user. But I made that object because I am trying to eliminate the code repetition.

Could someone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: @pst, but then how will the code look like? can u give an example?

Comment: (I am not sure why this question is getting downvoted .. VS designer woes can very annoying. Anyway, you can still eliminate code repetition without another constructor. Consider posting [the relevant parts of] what you have so far.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default no-arg constructor *must* be left in and it should call `InitializeComponents`. If that is done, then adding a *secondary* constructor should be OK and designer should not mess with it.

However, I would recommend not using overloaded constructors, but rather exposing Methods or Properties to accomplish the desired task for a WinForms control.

When in WinRome, do as the..

---

Example of secondary constructor:

```
// Leave this constructor - in the X.designer.cs file
public MyType () {
    InitializeComponents();
}

// Add your own constructor - in the X.cs file
public MyType (int x) : this() {
    // ..
}
```

---

Update: avoiding editing the "X.designer.cs" files by hand; these are for the designer. Instead, edit the mirroring "X.cs" file. Partial classes are used to spread up the designer code and your custom code between these two files.

Comment: pst, I understood this part. What I didn't understand is how to work this magic with the WinForms. Also you comment about properties is confusing. If I make a public property in this class and set it will it be the same as if I pass the parameter to the constructor? And in this case I will need to override the set function of the property to make the necessary controls, correct?Thank you.

Comment: @Igor It is need not the same, but they can achieve similar results. Imagine when you do `control.Text = "blah"`, vs. having a constructor the take in the text .. this is just how WinForm controls are setup/designed to work and they are heavily based on Properties. WinForms is *not* about being "side effect free" and the designer has no notion of a non-default constructor itself.

Comment: I made the change as you suggested in the code above, but it does not work. After changing something in the GUI editor I still end up fixing the code of Form1.Designer.cs. Any other idea?

Comment: Don't edit the design file -- that's *not* for you :) Edit the partial class file: `Form1.cs` (that's for you). It's okay that the secondary constructor is in a separate part of the [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

Comment: pst, When trying to change something in the GUI designer the constructor of my object is changed to look like: "this.MyType = new Form1.MyType(this.component);" in the file Form1.Designer.cs. Also not sure how to not change this file and make the changes in the Form1.cs. When I put the control on the form it will automatically generates an appropriate code for insertion, which will look like the code above. And I can't override this in the Form_Load event. Or am I? Thank you.

Comment: Almost forgot, this change will screw the GUI designer as it won't compile the form anymore and present the error message. I'm talking about the code change in the post above.